# If condition (if button pressed) in inline php code within html

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I'm trying to send a friend request when a button is pressed but my problem is that I get two alerts when the page refreshes and when I click the button is that because my php is inline within my html code? Thanks

[when the page refreshes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3WWM.png)

[when i click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4rYh.png)

```
<div class="alert alert-success fade in">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
<p><strong>Ey!</strong></p>

<?
$getusersquery=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from 360tery where userid='$otherusersid' LIMIT 4  ");
while($row5=mysqli_fetch_array($getusersquery))
   {
      $userusername=$row5['username'];
      $useremail=$row5['Email'];
      $userprofilepicture=$row5['Profilepicture'];
      $userfirstname=$row5['firstname'];
      $userlastname=$row5['lastname'];
      $user_profile_pic='/users/'.$userusername.'/profilepicture/'.$userprofilepicture;
      $userphoto = "<img src='.$user_profile_pic' id='avatarimg' class='img-circle' height='85' width='85'> <br> <br>";

      echo'<div class="well">';
      echo '<p><strong> '.$userfirstname.' '.$userlastname.'</strong> </p>';
      echo'<p>'.$userusername.'</p>';
      echo $userphoto;
      echo '<form action=""  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> ';
      echo '<input type="submit" name="addfriend" value="Add Friend" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">'; 
      echo '</div>';
    }
     if(isset($_POST['addfriend']))
     {                 
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Request sent !');</script>";
     }    
?>
```

Comment: If you show the rendered HTML, perhaps we can see why.

Comment: @mplungjan i've added screenshots

Comment: Using ajax would be useful in this case

Comment: @ABCatella An example would be very helpful and appreciated as i am a beginner in web development

Comment: Sure. But can wait till tomorrow, as I am using SO in mobile , and cannot write my answer in this mobile and update through laptop?

Comment: Im really running late to submit this project but sure anyway im waiting for your help and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//In your main page


            <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                <p><strong>Ey!</strong></p>
                <?
                $getusersquery=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from 360tery where userid='$otherusersid' LIMIT 4  ");
                while($row5=mysqli_fetch_array($getusersquery))
                   {
                      //here, added userid to use in button
                      $userid=$row5['userid'];
                      $userusername=$row5['username'];
                      $useremail=$row5['Email'];
                      $userprofilepicture=$row5['Profilepicture'];
                      $userfirstname=$row5['firstname'];
                      $userlastname=$row5['lastname'];
                      $user_profile_pic='/users/'.$userusername.'/profilepicture/'.$userprofilepicture;
                      $userphoto = "<img src='.$user_profile_pic' id='avatarimg' class='img-circle' height='85' width='85'> <br> <br>";

                      echo'<div class="well">';
                      echo '<p><strong> '.$userfirstname.' '.$userlastname.'</strong> </p>';
                      echo'<p>'.$userusername.'</p>';
                      echo $userphoto;
                      //Here changed form to button
                      echo '<button onclick="send_request('.$userid.')" name="addfriend" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Add Friend</button>'; 
                      echo '</div>';
                    }    
                ?>

        //Javascript - Ajax submit function
        <script>
            function send_request(userid){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: "userid="+userid,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>

    //In ajax.php page
    <?
    if(isset($_POST['userid'])){
        $userid=$_POST['userid'];
        if(your_condition_like_mysqliupdate_or_other_with_$userid) {
            echo "Friend Request sent";
        } else {
            echo "Friend Request NOT sent";
        }   
    }
    ?>
```

Please try this. Make sure you have closed DIV `alert` . I did not see it in your code

---

Some updates to your main.php

1. `data: {otherusersid: "$otherusersid", myuserid: "$myuserid"},`, here your are using `name` instead of `myuserid`
2. `$query=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT userid from 360tery where Email='$email'");`, here your are using `username` instead of `Email`
3. **VERY IMPORTANT: PHP IS CaSe SeNsItIvE.** You used sometimes `Username`,`Email` as `username`, `email` etc., Please use variables, mysql table, columns as designed in mysql.

Comment: @A B Catella Thankyou for the fast response, i've made the changes in your answer in my code accordingly and here is my code and error [Main.php](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6LW5zbHE5WTJWTzA/view?usp=sharing) [ajax.php](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6bmc5Z3RKdWprZGc/view?usp=sharing) [error.jpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6YVRxcG5sX3VjMHc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: i've added some variables in your code because i want to add my userid using sessions and its declared and im sure its working **$myuserid** and i want to add the request sent to that user's id **$otherusersid** and i also made sure my sql statmenet is working

Comment: Have you added javascript function I added on my code? It is saying `send_request` function not available

Comment: Yes i've did and sorry for uploading the wrong main.php file here is the code again [main.php](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6bGQzbUFwR2podTQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: 1. Change to `data: "otherusersid="+otherusersid+"&myuserid="+myuserid,`, 2. Jquery included? Because $.ajax requires jquery library. 3. Why you added `?>` at script end?

Comment: My jquery is included and that `?>` is removed added it by mistake and my line that have data is `data: data: "otherusersid="+otherusersid+"myuserid="+myuserid,` if i'm going correct then im still getting the error in my `error.jpg`

Comment: Can you show me full code of main.php? In double `data: data: ` is wrong and it is `+"&myuserid`. You are saying it is `main.php` and screenshot shows `updatetimeline.html`. Are you using .htaccess rewrite?

Comment: **Yes i do use .htaaccess** . This is my full code (didn't upload it from first because its large) [updatedtimeline.php](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6LVFDaWJ1X2xhb2c/view?usp=sharing) and sorry for the confusion but my `main.php` link is redirecting me to my main.php I've changed my ajax function data line to `data: "$otherusersid="+otherusersid "&myuserid="+myuserid,`

Comment: i get this alert [alert when i press add friend button] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6Vk8yWjM4a25GZW8/view?usp=sharing) and my .htaaccess file [.htaaccess](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6RF8xdFdFRHZWY2c/view?usp=sharing) sorry for being long on asking and answering but its getting me a while to solve this